# Is there a condition such that the $A$ action of a $A \rtimes H$-module is a restriction of the $H$-action?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra and $A$ a subalgebra of $H$ such that $A$ is a left coideal of $H$ (that is $\Delta(A) \subset H \otimes A$) and $A$ is preserved by the adjoint action of $H$.

Consider now the semi-direct product $A \rtimes H$. Modules of this algebra are vector spaces together with an an action of $A$ (denoted by $\triangleright_A$) and an action $H$ (denoted by $\triangleright_H$) such that for all $a \in A, h \in H, v \in V $ we have

$$ h \triangleright_H (a \triangleright_A v) = (h_{(1)}aS(h_{(2)}))\triangleright_A(h_{(3)} \triangleright_H v)$$

where we used the Sweedler notation.

Directly from the axioms of a Hopf algebra, one sees very easily that if $V$ is an $H$-module and the action of $A$ is just the restriction of the one of $H$, the above condition is fulfilled.

My question is about some kind of converse statement: is there some kind of condition on $A$ and/or $H$ that ensures that for any $A \rtimes H$ modules the action of $A$ is then just the restriction of the action of $H$? One would imagine that if $A$ is a "big" subalgebra there is not much room for the action of $H$ to be different.

Comment: Consider the subalgebra $B$ of $A\rtimes H$ spanned by elements of the form $S(a_1)\otimes a_2$. You can show that $a\mapsto S(a_1)\otimes a_2$ is an algebra isomorphism from $A$ to $B$. It then holds that a module is of the form you are interested in if and only if the subalgebra $B$ acts trivially on it. In principle, there will always be modules for which this is not the case- just take a non-trivial module of $B$ and induce it to $A\rtimes H$

Comment: @EhudMeir Thank you for your answer. I am a bit confused though. $A$ may not be a sub Hopf algebra so there is no reason for $S(a_1)$ to be in $A$.

Comment: Yes. This works if $A$ is a right coideal. For $A$ a left coideal I think that a slight variation of this formula will work.